# How to reinstall SQL Server Integration Services I've deinstalled from a Production server by mistake

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

In deinstalling a named instance of SQL Server 2012 from a Production server, inadvertantly, I selected SSIS as a product to deinstall.  Now, I need to reinstall it with the least disruption possible.

Answer (score 2):

Run the installer again.

[Installing/Configuring SSIS and SSRS to existing SQL Server 2008 database services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0115b0c-310f-47b9-bc4b-978239244de4/installingconfiguring-ssis-and-ssrs-to-existing-sql-server-2008-database-services?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

> > Run SQL Server setup program and on the “Feature Selection” page click the checkboxes associated with the features you would like to have installed. When finish, reapply any service pack the instance have applied before.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I deinstalled another named instance before doing this, it's going to make me restart the server before it lets me do the install of SSIS.  I'm betting no way to get around that, right?

Comment: I don't know. The removal of the named instance will probably require that you reboot to clear out anything left over, but the install shouldn't.